# how to put standard error bars on my ggplot2 2-factor bar graphic?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I've been trying for a while to change my current standard deviation bars into standard error bars in my bar plot.

This is the plot with mean+sd:

```
EGG <- data.frame(type = c("this", "this", "that", "that"),
                  chemcon = c(10,11,12,13),
                  day = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Monday", "Tuesday"))

EGG
#>    type chemcon     day
#> 1  this      10  Monday
#> 2  this      11 Tuesday
#> 3  that      12  Monday
#> 4  that      13 Tuesday

require(ggplot2)
aa <- aggregate(chemcon ~ day + type, data=EGG, FUN=mean)
bb <- aggregate(chemcon ~ day + type, data=EGG, FUN=sd)
cc <- merge(aa, bb, by=c("day", "type"))
colnames(cc)[3:4] <- c("mean", "sd")

ggplot(cc, aes(x = type, y = mean, fill = day))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position= "dodge") + #nb you can just use 'dodge' in barplots
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="", y="chemcon") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-sd,
                    ymax = mean+sd), 
                position = "dodge")
```

I tried to replace the function (FUN) of aggregate of "sd" with "se", no luck, then I tried to create "se" also with no luck:

```
se = sd(Egg$chemcon) / sqrt(length(Egg$chemcon))
```

The issue is because I must keep the "aggregate" function due to it working the best when trying to represent a two-factor bar plot, but haven't I seen anyone use it quite like this anywhere else with standard error. Can someone please help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: not valid apparently... `Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'std.error' not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `std.error()` from `plotrix` package as shown below

```
library(plotrix)
library(ggplot2)
EGG <- data.frame(type = rep(c("this", "this", "that", "that"),2),
                  chemcon = c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
                  day = rep(c("Monday", "Tuesday"),4))

EGG

aa <- aggregate(chemcon ~ day + type, data=EGG, FUN=mean)
bb <- aggregate(chemcon ~ day + type, data=EGG, FUN=sd)
ee <- aggregate(chemcon ~ day + type, data=EGG, FUN=std.error)  ##  from library(plotrix)
#ee <- aggregate(chemcon ~ day + type, data=EGG, FUN=sd(x)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x))) )
# cc <- aggregate(chemcon ~ day + type, data=EGG, FUN = function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), se = (sd(x)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))) ))
cc <- merge(aa, ee, by=c("day", "type"))
colnames(cc)[3:4] <- c("mean", "se")


ggplot(cc, aes(x = type, y = mean, fill = day))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position= "dodge") + #nb you can just use 'dodge' in barplots
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="", y="chemcon") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se,
                    ymax = mean+se), 
                position = "dodge")
```

[image: output]

Comment: It worked like a wonder! Thank you SO much, you have no idea how much you have helped me. People like you are why I love this community. My best regards to you and have a wonderful day.